# create chains of views joins so one view can 'see' across more than one join

Tags: views, entities

Assuming the individual joins work can we join multiple times across columns like this?... (BTW I've checked this first query and it does indeed work correctly)

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
ON a.a_id = b.references_a_id
LEFT JOIN c
ON b.references_c_id = c.c_id
LEFT JOIN d
ON c.references_d_id = d.d_id
```

As per the following table.column structure:

```
a.a_id
a.a_col

b.b_id
b.references_a_id
b.references_c_id
b.b_col

c.c_id
c.references_d_id
c.c_col

d.d_id
d.d_col
```

Is it possible to link these together in a view so that because we have the joins defined in hook_views_data_alter() we can have the following:

**pseudo-description of the Views setup:**

```
(views setup)

"SHOW" 'a'

...

"FIELDS" > "add" > overlay menu "Add fields" >
    a: a_id
    a: a_col
    b: b_id
    b: references_a_id
    b: references_c_id
    b: b_col
    c: c_id
    c: references_d_id
    c: c_col
    d: d_id
    d: d_col
```

So because this is not working for me... in hook_views_data_alter()

```
$data['b']['table']['join']['a']['left_field'] = 'a_id';
$data['b']['table']['join']['a']['left_table'] = 'a';
$data['b']['table']['join']['a']['field'] = 'references_a_id';
$data['b']['table']['join']['c']['left_field'] = 'c_id';
$data['b']['table']['join']['c']['left_table'] = 'c';
$data['b']['table']['join']['c']['field'] = 'references_c_id';
$data['c']['table']['join']['d']['left_field'] = 'd_id';
$data['c']['table']['join']['d']['left_table'] = 'd';
$data['c']['table']['join']['d']['field'] = 'references_d_id';
```

... I wonder if I should be doing something bizarre like this...

```
$data['b']['table']['join']['a']['left_field'] = 'a_id';
$data['b']['table']['join']['a']['left_table'] = 'a';
$data['b']['table']['join']['a']['field'] = 'references_a_id';
$data['b']['table']['join']['c']['left_field'] = 'c_id';
$data['b']['table']['join']['c']['left_table'] = 'c';
$data['b']['table']['join']['c']['field'] = 'references_c_id';
$data['b']['table']['join']['c']['left_table']['c']['join']['d']['left_field'] = 'd_id';
$data['b']['table']['join']['c']['left_table']['c']['join']['d']['left_table'] = 'd';
$data['b']['table']['join']['c']['left_table']['c']['join']['d']['field'] = 'references_d_id';
```

Comment: I have a feeling that what I need to do is make more use of Relationships...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a relationship to the mix and that's opened up two extra sets of fields ('c' and 'd') I can't explain why, I think it's something to do with the joins that were already setup on these base tables. This then meant that when I bridged them with the relationship it opened it all up.

example:

```
$data['a']['a_id']['relationship']['handler'] = 'views_handler_relationship';
$data['a']['a_id']['relationship']['base'] = 'b';
$data['a']['a_id']['relationship']['base field'] = 'references_a_id';
    (... etc.)
```